# React CSSTransitionGroup does not work even with key being set

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have been trying since yesterday to make an animation to my image carousel. As far as I understand, you wrap the content to be animated with the CSSTransitionGroup and make sure it stays in the dom and also specify a unique key to each child of the transition group. I believe I have followed all this yet I see no transition.

One thing worth to mention, While I was trying to get this working I suspected if something could be wrong with the key, so I tried setting the key with a random string. The key would change every-time the state changes, and for some unknown reason I could see the animation. Can someone explain this to me.

I am not sure where I am going wrong, whether the version of transition group or in setting the key to children, No clue !

Below is the code replicating my problem.

```
var CSSTransitionGroup = React.addons.CSSTransitionGroup


class Images extends React.Component {
    constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        showComponent: false,
    }
  }

  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps){
    if (this.props.name === nextProps.showComponentName){
        this.setState({
        showComponent: true,
      })
    } else {
      this.setState({
        showComponent: false,
      })
    }
  }

  render() {
    if (this.state.showComponent){
        return (
        <img src={this.props.url} />
      )
    } else {
        return null;
    }
  }
}


class TransitionExample extends React.Component {

  constructor (props) {
    super(props);
    this.onClick = this.onClick.bind(this);
    this.state= {
        showComponentName: null,
    }
  }

    onClick(button) {
    this.setState({
        showComponentName: button.currentTarget.textContent,
    })
  }

    render() {
        var imageData = [
        "http://lorempixel.com/output/technics-q-c-640-480-9.jpg",
            "http://lorempixel.com/output/food-q-c-640-480-8.jpg",
            "http://lorempixel.com/output/city-q-c-640-480-9.jpg",
            "http://lorempixel.com/output/animals-q-c-640-480-3.jpg"
    ];

        var images = [];
        for (var i in imageData) {
            i = parseInt(i, 10);
            images.push(
                <Images url={imageData[i]} showComponentName={this.state.showComponentName} name={imageData[i]} key={imageData[i]} />
            );
        }

    return (
        <div>
        <div>
        <button onClick={this.onClick}>{imageData[0]}</button>
        <button onClick={this.onClick}>{imageData[1]}</button>
        <button onClick={this.onClick}>{imageData[2]}</button>
        <button onClick={this.onClick}>{imageData[3]}</button>
      </div>
        <div className="transitions">
        <CSSTransitionGroup
            transitionName="viewphoto"
          transitionEnterTimeout={2000}
          transitionLeaveTimeout={2000}
          transitionAppearTimeout={2000}
          transitionAppear={true}
          transitionEnter={true}
          transitionLeave={true}>
                        {images}
        </CSSTransitionGroup>
            </div>
      </div>
    );
    }
}


ReactDOM.render(
  <TransitionExample />,
  document.getElementById('container')
);
```

I am also providing the link to the example on [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/manjunath_satyamurthy/bc4kuhg8/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your code is that `images` is always an array of elements that don't mount/unmount. The correct approach for this is to **change the child**. For example, if you substitute the return of the render method of your fiddle with this:

```
return (
    <div>
    <div>
    <button onClick={this.onClick}>{imageData[0]}</button>
    <button onClick={this.onClick}>{imageData[1]}</button>
    <button onClick={this.onClick}>{imageData[2]}</button>
    <button onClick={this.onClick}>{imageData[3]}</button>
  </div>
    <div className="transitions">
    <CSSTransitionGroup
        transitionName="viewphoto"
      transitionEnterTimeout={2000}
      transitionLeaveTimeout={2000}
      transitionAppearTimeout={2000}
      transitionAppear={true}
      transitionEnter={true}
      transitionLeave={true}>
          <img src={this.state.showComponentName} key={this.state.showComponentName}/>
    </CSSTransitionGroup>
        </div>
  </div>
);
```

The animation works! Using a simple `img` instead of your `Images` component and giving it the image url (this only works when you have clicked a button, `showComponentName` should be initialized to show the first image). You could also use a custom component of course, but the point here is **that the children elements of CSSTransitionGroup must be changed if you want the animation to trigger because otherwise you are always rendering the same four `Images` components no matter whether they return the img or not**. You might want to check out [react-css-transition-replace](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-css-transition-replace) since it usually works better when it comes to replacing.

Comment: Oh, thank you very much for your answer. I had this thought that my Images component was being mounted/unmounted depending on the prop. I am a little confused now with when does react mount/unmount.